# How to de/serialize a map with template class using boost::multiprecision::mpq_rational

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, dictionary

I have the following template class:

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>
template <class T>
class A {
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
        ar & a;
}
public:
  T a;
};
```

that I use to create a map.

```
map<A<boost::array<int,2> >, int> mmm;
```

I can use the header files provided by boost to serialize/deserialize this code using:

```
 ifstream ifs("filename");
 boost::archive::text_iarchive iarch(ifs);
 boost::serialization::load<boost::archive::text_iarchive,int,A<boost::array<int,2> > >(iarch,mmm,1);
```

Question: I would like to use `boost::multiprecision::mpq_rational` instead of `int` inside the array. However I get a long error with the main complaint being that gmp_backend does not have a serialize method:

```
....
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: ‘struct boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_rational’ has no member named ‘serialize’
     t.serialize(ar, file_version);
     ^
```

Is there an easy fix using boost/serialization/map.hpp with mpq_rational?
Thanks,

Comment: In actual fact you should have reduced the question to /just/ ask how to serialize `mpq_rational`, since the rest is not essential to your problem (or the solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's *passthrough* support for Boost Multiprecision serialization:

> *Classes `number`, `debug_adaptor`, `logged_adaptor` and `rational_adaptor`
>   have "pass through" serialization support which requires the underlying 
>   backend to be serializable.*
>
> Backends `cpp_int`, `cpp_bin_float`, `cpp_dec_float` and `float128` have 
>   full support for Boost.Serialization.

That is to say, it's supported *iff* the backend supports it: **[mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=boost-users&m=137476708507485&w=2)**:

> `>` *Does/will multiprecesion have support for boost::serialization?*
>
> *Good question, and no not yet.  I guess it should do though... it's hard 
>   though as some backends (for example GMP's mpf_t) don't round trip to and 
>   from string representations, and have an internal structure that probably 
>   shouldn't be relied upon :-*

You can:

- use `cpp_rational` (as it is supported implicitly by the above doc excerpt)
- use Boost Rational: [How to serialize boost::rational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563255/how-to-serialize-boostrational/22564432#22564432)
- use raw `mpz_*` API to serialize, see e.g. [How to serialize a GMP rational number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970714/how-to-serialize-a-gmp-rational-number/21973924#21973924)
- you can explicitly add serialization support for the backend (note that using the gmp API's will be more efficient)

  ```
  namespace boost { namespace serialization {

      template <typename Archive>
          void save(Archive& ar, ::boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_rational const& r, unsigned /*version*/)
          {
              std::string tmp = r.str(10000, std::ios::fixed);
              ar & tmp;
          }

      template <typename Archive>
          void load(Archive& ar, ::boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_rational& r, unsigned /*version*/)
          {
              std::string tmp;
              ar & tmp;
              r = tmp.c_str();
          }

  } }

  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(::boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_rational)
  ```

Here's a demo **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45188200ad69be0d)** with a simple roundtrip test.

#### Full Listing

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/rational_adaptor.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace boost { namespace serialization {

    template <typename Archive>
        void save(Archive& ar, ::boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_rational const& r, unsigned /*version*/)
        {
            std::string tmp = r.str(10000, std::ios::fixed);
            ar & tmp;
        }

    template <typename Archive>
        void load(Archive& ar, ::boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_rational& r, unsigned /*version*/)
        {
            std::string tmp;
            ar & tmp;
            r = tmp.c_str();
        }

} }

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(::boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_rational)

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <map>

template <class T>
class A {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & a;
        }

  public:
    T a;
    bool operator<(A const& o) const { return a<o.a; }
};

#include <sstream>

using KeyElement = boost::multiprecision::mpq_rational;
using Key        = A<boost::array<KeyElement,2> >;
using Data       = std::map<Key, int>;

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    {
        Data mmm { 
            { Key {{{KeyElement { 1, 2 }, KeyElement { 3, 4 }} }}, 5 }, 
            { Key {{{KeyElement { 6, 7 }, KeyElement { 8, 9 }} }}, 42 },
        };
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);

        oa << mmm;
    }

    std::cout << "Serialized:\t" << ss.str() << "\n";

    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive iarch(ss);
        Data mmm; 
        iarch >> mmm;

        std::cout << "Roundtrip:\t";
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
        oa << mmm;
    }
}
```