# Writing boost::multiprecision data type to binary file

Tags: c++, boost, ofstream, multiprecision

I was using the `boost::multiprecision::uint128_t` type in order to perform bitwise operations on a 128 bit value. However I am having trouble writing the 128 bit value out to a binary file. Specifically with the need to pad out the value with zeros.

As an example if the `uint128_t` value was `0x123456` then looking at the file in the hex editor I would want the sequence:

`56 34 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <fstream>

boost::multiprecision::uint128_t temp = 0x123456;
std::ofstream ofile("test.bin", std::ios::binary);
ofile.write((char*)&temp, 16);
ofile.close();
```

Instead the binary file ends up with a value:

`56 34 12 00 CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC`

I can see the the boost backend for the `uint128_t` template appears to store the 128 bits as four 32 bit values. And has a "limb" value which indicates how many 32 bit values are in use. When the 32 bit values are not in use they are filled with `0xCCCCCCCC`. So the `ofstream.write` is walking through the array of characters and writing out the `0xC`'s.

Is there something I am missing in the boost library to help write this out correctly, or will I need to convert the `uint128_t` value into some another data type?

Comment: the `(char*)` reinterpret_cast is ***evil*** and (obviously) doesn't work. See related answers on how to serialize using boost serialization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28705686/85371

Answer (score 0):

I dived into it, you can write a utility to write the contiguous limbs as POD objects:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06b298e8b1c257cb)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <fstream>

template <typename BigInt, typename Backend = typename BigInt::backend_type>
void write_binary(std::ostream& os, BigInt const& number) {
    static_assert(boost::is_pod<typename Backend::local_limb_type>::value, "not allowed");

    os.write(
            reinterpret_cast<char const*>(number.backend().limbs()), 
            number.backend().size()*sizeof(typename Backend::local_limb_type)
        );
}

int main()
{
    using uint128_t = boost::multiprecision::uint128_t;

    std::ofstream ofs("binary.dat", std::ios::binary);
    write_binary(ofs, uint128_t(42));
}
```

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 2a00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  *...............
```

I'm afraid this isn't portable (it may depend on the availability of compiler intrinsics for 128 bit numbers). At least it's type safe.

Comment: does it have boost::serialization support?

Comment: @Sergei oh, hah. That comment slipped through the cracks. Let me fix that up: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/serial.html

Comment: @Sergei See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/28705686/85371, and the linked posts. Also tangentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30111778/85371

Comment: So how to convert  uint8 data[] = {56 34 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00} to a uint128_t? What I mean is, how to construct a uint128_t by a byte array?

Comment: @alpha that's a different question. If you can't find info on that or get stuck implementing it, you might post a question