# Generate operator== using Boost Serialization?

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

**Problem:** I have a set of classes for which I have already implemented *boost serialization* methods. Now, I want to add an `operator==` to one class that contains many of the other classes as its members. This comparison should be straightforward: A deep, member wise comparison.

**Idea:** Since the existing serialization methods already tell the compiler everything it needs to know, I wonder if this can be used to generate efficient  comparison operators.

**Approach 1:** The simplest thing would be to compare strings containing serializations of the objects to be compared. The runtime of this approach is probably much slower than handcrafted `operator==` implementations.

**Approach 2:** Implement a specialized boost serialization archive for comparisons. However, implementing this is much more complicated and time consuming than implementing either handcrafted operators or approach 1.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing recently for hashing of serializable types:

- [Hash an arbitrary precision value (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097385/hash-an-arbitrary-precision-value-boostmultiprecisioncpp-int/30111778#30111778)

Here I "abused" boost serialization to get a hash function for any Boost Multi Precision number type (that has a serializable backend).

The approach given in the linked answer is strictly more lightweight and much easier to implement than writing a custom archive type. Instead, I wrote a custom custom Boost Iostreams sink to digest the raw data. 
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

```
struct hash_sink {
    hash_sink(size_t& seed_ref) : _ptr(&seed_ref) {}

    typedef char         char_type;
    typedef io::sink_tag category;

    std::streamsize write(const char* s, std::streamsize n) {
        boost::hash_combine(*_ptr, boost::hash_range(s, s+n));
        return n;
    }
  private:
    size_t* _ptr;
};
```

This is highly efficient because it doesn't store the archive anywhere in the process. (So it sidesteps the dreadful inefficiency of ***Approach 1***)

---

#### Applying to Equality Comparison

Sadly, you can't easily equality compare in streaming mode (unless you can be sure that both streams can be consumed in tandem, which is a bit of finicky assumption).

Instead you would probably use something like `boost::iostreams::device::array_sink` or `boost::iostreams::device::back_insert_device` to receive the raw data.

If memory usage is a concern you might want to compress it in memory (Boost Iostreams comes with the required filters for zip/bzip too). But I guess this is not your worry - as you would likely not be trying to avoid duplicating code in that case. You could just implement the comparison directly.