# Why I cannot use neither std::unordered_map nor boost::unordered_map with boost::multiprecision types?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, unordered-map, multiprecision

I am trying to create a `STL` (or `boost`) `unordered_map` with `boost::mulprecision` types e.g. `cpp_int` but `gcc` throws errors after trying to insert elements to this container.

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{
  cpp_int z(123123123);
  cpp_int x(123123123);

  boost::unordered_map<cpp_int, cpp_int> data;

  // line below will throw compilation errors
  //data.insert(std::make_pair(z,x));
  return 0;
}
```

Full error log is [here](http://pastebin.com/DGgJCCYv)

First of the errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:529:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/functional/hash.hpp:6,
                 from /usr/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/unordered_map.hpp:16,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp: In instantiation of
  ........
main.cpp:13:34:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:269:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘hash_value(const boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<> >&)’
             return hash_value(val);
                                  ^
```

Is there a limitation to `STL`/`boost` container usage regarding `boost`'s multiprecision types?
I am using boost 1.54.

**EDIT**:

The [question of which this might be a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097385/hash-an-arbitrary-precision-value-boostmultiprecisioncpp-int) uses `boost::multiprecision`'s serialization support which has been added in boost 1.56 (at least according to differences in docs [@1.55](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/serial.html) and [@1.56](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/serial.html).

Also, in that question there has been no other approaches mentioned to solve this issue without serialization support in `boost::multiprecision`.

Comment: As it says, no `hash_value` function exists for this type. You need to write one.

Comment: Read the documentation for unordered collections.  They are basically hash tables, and as such need a hash function.  The error message you are getting is quite clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "[question of which this might be a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097385/hash-an-arbitrary-precision-value-boostmultiprecisioncpp-int)" documents a working technique in the question itself - hashing the string representation:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

template <typename T>
struct hash_str
{
    size_t operator()(const T& t) const { return std::hash<std::string>()(t.str()); }
};

int main()
{
  cpp_int z(123123123);
  cpp_int x(123123123);

  boost::unordered_map<cpp_int, cpp_int, hash_str<cpp_int>> data;

  data.insert(std::make_pair(z,x));
}
```

Notes:

- I don't know if `cpp_int::str()` outputs the full precision the type stores, but if it doesn't then distinct values yielding the same `str()` and hence hash will collide in the same bucket in the hash table, which won't break the functionality but moves away from O(1) towards O(N) performance.  So, if by default `str()` doesn't display full precision but there's a way to force it, that would be a good idea if you deal in lots of values differing very slightly.
- As with all uses of floating point types as keys, be careful as tiny rounding differences can lead to existing map entries not being found/matched, and hence unintended "duplicates" etc..

It your program is too slow *and* the profile proves the hashing is the cause, *then* worry about alternatives or upgrading boost....