# How to display C++ Boost Library multi-precision big integers in binary form?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multiprecision

I'm new to Boost and trying to use its multi-precision library to multiply very large inputs:

```
mp::uint1024_t my_1024_bit_int1 = 0b00100101101000100010010...010101;
mp::uint1024_t my_1024_bit_int2 = 0b0010101001000101000010100000001001...01010111; // bigger in practice
mp::uint1024_t my_1024_bit_result = my_1024_bit_int2*my_1024_bit_int1;
```

I need to be able to save the result as a string in binary form. I have tried to access the number of "limbs" in the integer:

```
int limbs = my_1024_bit_result.backend.limbs();
```

and then iterate through each limb and use the `bitset` function to convert each limb to a binary string, but it did not work.

How else could I achieve this?

Comment: I believe you're overthinking this.  Pretend you'e not using the multi-precision library -- how would you generate the string?  Wouldn't it be the very same code, except the `int` type would be replaced with `cpp_int`?

Comment: side remark: are you sure your first 2 lines work properly for numbers with > 64 bits?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I suppose they should be string initialized indeed, but the `0b` format is not support by their constructor

Answer (score 1):

If you actually meant binary digits:

```
template <typename Integer>
std::string to_bin(Integer num) {
    auto sign = num.sign();
    num = abs(num);

    std::string result;
    while (num) {
        result += "01"[int(num % 2)];
        num /= 2;
    }
    result += sign<0? "b0-": "b0";
    std::reverse(begin(result), end(result));
    return result;
}
```

> Note how it supports signed types as well

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63ed4380b41c5153)**

```
int main() {
    mp::uint1024_t a=0b00100101101000100010010010101;
    mp::uint1024_t b=0b001010100100010100001010000000100101010111; // bigger in practice
    mp::uint1024_t c = a * b;

    std::cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << c << "\n";
    std::cout << "\n" << to_bin(a) << " * " << to_bin(b) << "\n = " << to_bin(c) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

78922901 * 726187641175 = 57312835311878048675

0b100101101000100010010010101 * 0b1010100100010100001010000000100101010111
 = 0b110001101101100000000110000000111101001010111101001000101110100011

### Serialization?

In case you meant "binary serialization", use serialization:

- [Writing boost::multiprecision data type to binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090325/writing-boostmultiprecision-data-type-to-binary-file/30090463#30090463)

Comment: I would replace the divide by 2 with a right shift, but this is the definitely the right way to do this.