# How to write a boost serialization wrapper for existing class types

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have my own class containing the following data:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/time_serialize.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
using namespace boost::archive;

class Foo {
// [...]

unsigned int m_length;  
std::vector<boost::posix_time::ptime> m_vecTimestamps;
std::vector<double> m_vecA;
std::vector<double> m_vecB;
std::vector<Point2d> m_vecPos;
```

Since I included the appropriate headers I am even able to serialize ptime:

```
// Still class Foo
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) { 
        ar & m_length; 
        ar & m_vecTimestamps; 
        ar & m_vecA;
        ar & m_vecB;
        ar & m_vecPos; // ooops, error
    }
```

Well, there is no approach to serialize Point2d since this class is delivered by a further third party library (contains simply 2 double values). So what are my options to write a wrapper which can be used within Foo::serialize? I would like to easily read and write that vector too. An easy example would be nice.

I tried to have a look at time_serialize.hpp but I do not understand how to write a similar approach for Point2d respectively other class types which can not be modified by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boost serialization tutorial contains both an [intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#simplecase) and a [non-intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#nonintrusiveversion) example. You need the non-intrusive version which allows you to add a `serialize` function for `Point2d`:

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, Point2d & p, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & p.x;
    ar & p.y;
}
} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

Comment: This works fine for the simple Point2d class. But is there also a solution for the following class: http://codepad.org/1Qp1qSuK

Comment: @Anonymous why would that be different? use `ar & b.value()`

Comment: I get two compiler errors. First: "C2679: Binary operator '&': no operator found which accepts 'double'". Second error: "C2088: '&': Invalid for class" (Roughly translated since I am using another language)

Comment: I am accepting your solutions since it answers the original question. Thanks for that! But I would be glad if you could test and extend your answer with the Bar-class. Find an example here: http://codepad.org/r0Hxc33V

Comment: @Anonymous `operator&` wants its arguments passed via non-const reference, which is not possible for the temporary return value of the function `value()`. You could create a temporary copy of the value and serialize that: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CD6Iyh1tXse9bTOC

Comment: @m.s. that advice doesn't work. Unless you never want to deserialize. There's a reason why lvalues are required/assumed by the serialization framework.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer

### Generically serializing families of types

If you want to non-intrusively implement `serialize` for points in a generic way, for a "family" of generic types with some common traits, look here e.g.

- [How to de/serialize a map with template class using boost::multiprecision::mpq_rational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101517/how-to-de-serialize-a-map-with-template-class-using-boostmultiprecisionmpq-r/26117639?s=1|3.5585#26117639)
- [boost serialization of mpfr_float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703639/boost-serialization-of-mpfr-float/28705686#28705686)
- [Hash an arbitrary precision value (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097385/hash-an-arbitrary-precision-value-boostmultiprecisioncpp-int/30111778?s=3|0.9528#30111778) (which uses binary serialization to do the heavy lifting)
- For `dynamic_bitset` I've recently shown two versions:

  - non-intrusive (slightly inefficient): [How to serialize boost::dynamic_bitset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006792/how-to-serialize-boostdynamic-bitset/31014564#31014564)
  - [How to serialize boost::dynamic_bitset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006792/how-to-serialize-boostdynamic-bitset/31015623#31015623) ; This is actually interesting, because it is "hybrid". The only *intrusive* bit is two lines of code:

    ```
    // forward declaration for optional zero-copy serialization support 
    class serialize_impl; 
    friend class serialize_impl;
    ```

    The rest of the implementation can be hidden in a TU and only compiled if the dependency on Boost Serialization is desired.

### Serializing with getters

A note about the advice:

> *[...]You could create a temporary copy of the value and serialize that:  –  m.s. [54 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159911/how-to-write-a-boost-serialization-wrapper-for-existing-class-types#comment50331210_31160189)*

Don't do that! At the very least you need separate load/save handling there. But realistically, just use the last approach shown above, where `serialize_impl` has full friend access to the class implementation.

If you really can't, you'll have use `load/save` and possibly `load_/save_construct_data` in case your type is not default-constructible